# How do I make a continuous loop with the animate method?

Tags: framerjs

How does one continuous loop an animation using `animate`? In this example, all I want to do is endlessly rotate a white square.

```
myBall = new Layer
    x: 100
    y: 100
    width: 200
    height: 200
    borderRadius: "20px"
    backgroundColor: "#FFF"

myBall.animate
    properties:
        rotationZ: 360
    time: 1
myBall.on Events.AnimationEnd, ->
    this.animate
        properties:
            rotationZ: 360
        time: 1
    this.backgroundColor = "#666"
```

After the first 360˚ z rotation, the background color will be changed to #666, but the animations will cease. I think it would be ideal if `repeat: -1` indicated continuous without having to listen for `AnimationEnd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the first animation rotates the layer to 360° you try to rotate it *again* to 360°, which returns in a visual non-existing animation. 
the solution for this is to set `myBall.rotationZ = 0` right before you start rotating again. in your code:

```
myBall.on Events.AnimationEnd, ->
    this.rotationZ = 0 # reset to back to zero
    this.animate
        properties:
            rotationZ: 360
        time: 1
```

### Other solution using `new Animation`

you can do this with states or an animation function, which results in cleaner code:

```
rotateAnim = new Animation
    layer: myBall
    properties:
        rotationZ: 360
    time: 1

rotateAnim.start() # kick if off once

rotateAnim.on "end", ->
    myBall.rotationZ = 0 # need to reset to zero so we can animate to 360 again
    rotateAnim.start()
```

Comment: I couldn't get the `new Animation` solution to work.

Answer (score 0):

As [frischmilch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589805/how-do-i-make-a-continuous-loop-with-the-animate-method#answer-25596813) suggested, you can also use the `new Animation` method, but his code was a little off:

```
# Create animation
animation = new Animation({
    layer: myBall
    properties:
        rotationZ: 360
    time: 1
})
# Start animation
animation.start()
# Loop animation
animation.on Events.AnimationEnd, ->
    # Reset rotation before looping
    myBall.rotationZ = 0
    animation.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use `reverse()` to create the reverse animation and trigger it.

```
animation = new Animation 
    layer: bookmark
    properties:
        scale: 1.08
    time: 1
    curve: Bezier.easeInOut

animation.start()

animation.onAnimationEnd ->
    reversedAnimation = animation.reverse()
    reversedAnimation.start()
    reversedAnimation.onAnimationEnd ->
        animation.start()
```

And [here it is](http://www.giphy.com/gifs/l0IxZgN7sqzEZpPuE) in action.