# Repeating, infinite animation loop using framer.js

Tags: framerjs

I'm trying to create a pulsating, looping animation effect using framer.js
I've loaded an image into a layer and I'd like to scale it up and down continuously. I can't figure out how to scale it down and loop through the animation indefinitely. This is what I currently have:

```
imageLayer = new Layer({x:0, y:0, width:128, height:128, image:"images/icon.png"})
imageLayer.center()

animationA = new Animation({
    layer: imageLayer,
    properties: {scale: 2.0},
    curve: "ease-in-out"
})


animationA.start()
```

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589805/how-do-i-make-a-continuous-loop-with-the-animate-method

Comment: This seems to work if I try to animate a layer that doesn't contain an image, but unfortunately not with an image layer...

Answer (score 3):

solved it like this:

```
imageLayer = new Layer({x:0, y:0, width:128, height:128, image:"images/icon.png"})
imageLayer.x = 100
imageLayer.y = 100

animationA = new Animation({
    layer: imageLayer,
    properties: {scale: 2.0},
    curve: "linear",
    time: 0.4

})

animationB = new Animation({
    layer: imageLayer,
    properties: {scale: 1.0},
    curve: "linear",
    time: 0.2

})

animationA.start()

animationA.on(Events.AnimationEnd, function() {
    animationB.start()
  });

animationB.on(Events.AnimationEnd, function() {
    animationA.start()
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome.. thanks for this. I fixed your code so it's all in coffeescript.

```
imageLayer = new Layer({x:0, y:0, width:128, height:128})
imageLayer.x = 100
imageLayer.y = 100

animationA = new Animation({
    layer: imageLayer,
    properties: {scale: 2},
    curve: "linear",
    time: 0.2
})

animationB = new Animation({
    layer: imageLayer,
    properties: {scale: 1.0},
    curve: "linear",
    time: 0.6
})

animationA.start()

animationA.on Events.AnimationEnd, ->
    animationB.start()

animationB.on Events.AnimationEnd, ->
    animationA.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it. It uses a single animation variable instead of 2.

```
animationTime = 1.8

animation = new Animation
    layer: sketch.spinner
    properties: 
        rotation: 360
    curve: "linear"
    time: animationTime

animation.start()

Utils.interval animationTime, ->
    #reset the animation
    sketch.spinner.rotation = 0
    animation.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Animation.reverse()` for this:

```
layerA = new Layer
    point: Align.center

scaling = new Animation
    layer: layerA
    properties: 
        scale: 2
    curve: "ease-in-out"

pulse = ->
    scaling.start()
    scaling.onAnimationEnd ->
        #Reverse the scaling animation
        scaling = scaling.reverse()
        #Sart the animation again
        pulse()

# Start of the pulse animation  
pulse()
```

However, if you have a animation that ends at the same point as it begins, you can use the recently introduced `looping: true` parameter of `Animation`:

```
layerA.animate
    properties: 
        rotation: 360
    curve: "linear"
    time: 5
    looping: true
```

Full prototype here: http://share.framerjs.com/hvex1plbkiqt/

Answer (score 0):

## Simple scaling example.

Two key points:

1) Use `reverse()` to create the reverse animation.

2) After each animation ends, trigger the other animation to start.

```
animation = new Animation 
    layer: bookmark
    properties:
        scale: 1.08
    time: 1
    curve: Bezier.easeInOut

animation.start()

animation.onAnimationEnd ->
    reversedAnimation = animation.reverse()
    reversedAnimation.start()
    reversedAnimation.onAnimationEnd ->
        animation.start()
```

And [here it is](http://www.giphy.com/gifs/l0IxZgN7sqzEZpPuE) in action.

Answer (score 0):

You could use States too.
https://framer.com/getstarted/guides/prototype#states

```
LayerA.states.flashGreen =
    color: "#00F082"
    shadowColor: "#00F082"
    shadowBlur: 10
    shadowSpread: 3
    animationOptions:
        time: 1
        curve: Bezier.ease

layerA.stateCycle()
layerA.onAnimationStop -> layerA.stateCycle()
```